# Basic Question in networking - why max data size of ip datagram 65535 BYTES and not 65535 bits?

Tags: computer-networks, communication-protocols, ip

I recently started computer networks with some understanding of algorithms and discrete mathematics. I am completely new. Kindly elaborate following -

data size of ip datagram = 16bits. So with this $2^{16} -1 = 65536$ 16 bit patterns can be generated. 
My doubt:

1. Do we say each 16 bit pattern is 1 IP datagram or all those 65536 patterns as 1 IP Datagram?
2. If i consider all 65536 patterns as max data size, then max ip datagram size $= 65536$ patterns size$ = 65536*16 $ bits $= 65536*16/8$  bytes $= 65536*2$ bytes

Answer (score 3):

16 bits is not the *size* of the IP datagram; it is the amount of bits required to *encode its length*. Hence, you can have datagrams of length up to 65536 octets (i.e., bytes), as described in [RFC 760](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc760):

> Total Length:  16 bits

> Total Length is the length of the datagram, measured in octets,
> including internet header and data.  This field allows the length of
> a datagram to be up to 65,535 octets.

Notice 65536 is not a prescribed length, that is, the length of the datagram is (or can be) *variable*.

---

Now, to answer your two questions:

> Do we say each 16 bit pattern is 1 IP datagram or all those 65536 patterns as 1 IP Datagram?

Each octet pattern of up to 16-bit length is a datagram. In informal parlance, a datagram is simply a packet which IP adds its header to. You could call the set of all possible patterns a "datagram space", though I doubt that's standard terminology. (You might care to ask that in a separate question.)

> If i consider all 65536 patterns as max data size, then max ip datagram size =65536 patterns size=65536∗16 bits =65536∗16/8 bytes =65536∗2 bytes

I'm not sure I see a question here. Though I suppose any one you had is answered by my remark about the datagram length above.